# What happend to the ros-electric-erratic-robot package on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I was looking for the ros-electric-erratic-robot package on ubuntu 11.10 without success?
On 11.04 I was able to install the package with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-erratic-robot
```

but it does not work on 11.10

Any idear?

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12003/what-happend-to-the-ros-electric-erratic-robot-package-on-ubuntu-11.10/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2011-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is working now.
I was able to install the erratic_robot on electric via the ubuntu 11.10 package management.

Greetings

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-12-12**:
Great, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Build farm logs](http://build.willowgarage.com/view/devel_electric/job/devel_electric_erratic_robot_oneiric_amd64/lastFailedBuild/console) show that the build failed because pr2_simulator is not built on oneiric, although [build status](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html) page shows that it was released and built. Can willowgarage folks comment on what's going on?

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1